# Android to PC transfer using a USB

Tags: java, android, file-transfer

Is there a way to transfer files stored on the android to the PC when the phone is connected with USB? A sync function of some sort. I would like to have a one button USB transfer option in my app but I cant figure out how to do it. Please point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can follow these steps:

1. configure Tethering & portable hotspot
2. connect the computer to the hotspot
3. start some kind of server on the computer
4. copy the files using an android client for the server chosen in 4